# Easiest way to code for hover over image

Tags: html

I have a basic idea for an image of a human being, where the user can hover their mouse over different areas of the image (for example, over the feet, or the lumbar spine) which will activate code that can display information on various clinical conditions pertinent to the 'hovered' area. I appreciate this is a very basic question, but what is the best and simplest way to program for this?

Comment: Read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use map tag. Draw over the image the different parts, with an id for each one. Then, you can display different info with javascript when user made over a section.

map tag info:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Comment: Some examples: 

[1] http://www.lassenglobal.com/en/map-search
 
 [2] http://www.currantessinfronteras.com/